# Deformation retract of cylinder of CW complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

This is probably a very simple question, but I'm having some trouble with it. Let $X$ be a CW complex. I am trying to show that $X\times[0,1]$, as a CW complex (so not necessarily product topology), deformation retracts onto $X\times\{0\}$.

If we were working with the product topology, the map $F\colon X\times[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow X\times[0,1]$ given by
$$(x,s,t)\mapsto (x,s(1-t))$$
should work.

But for a general CW complex the topology on $X\times[0,1]$ may be finer than that of the product topology. I assume that the map I am looking for is the same map, but how do I show that it is continuous?

Comment: $[0, 1]$ is locally compact, so the product topology on $X \times [0, 1]$ coincides with the CW topology.

Comment: @JHF Of course it does. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Vasting Still anything to be clarified?